# How to export xml from excel (xml source) with apache poi (ready to use other libs). Java, Kotlin

Tags: java, excel, xml, kotlin, apache-poi

Need to create xml file from excel (source xml).

I have excel map.

[image: 1]

I need to get the following xml file.

```
<report code="" form="" format-version="" period="" shifr="" version="" year="">
    <title>
        <item name="okpo" value=""/>
        <item name="name" value=""/>
        <item name="leader_fio" value=""/>
        <item name="responsible_post" value=""/>
        <item name="responsible_fio" value=""/>
        <item name="phone" value=""/>
        <item name="mail" value=""/>
    </title>
    <sections>
        <section code="1">
            <row code="1" s1="">
                <col code="1">189451</col>
                <col code="2">4562</col>
                <col code="3">184037</col>
                <col code="4">852</col>
                <col code="5">0</col>
                <col code="6">0</col>
                <col code="7">31424</col>
            </row>
            <row code="2" s1="">
                <col code="1">0</col>
                <col code="2">0</col>
                <col code="3">0</col>
                <col code="4">0</col>
                <col code="5">0</col>
                <col code="6">0</col>
                <col code="7">0</col>
            </row>
        </section>
        <section code="2">
            <row code="1" s1="">
                <col code="1">189451</col>
                <col code="2">4562</col>
                <col code="3">184037</col>
                <col code="4">852</col>
                <col code="5">0</col>
                <col code="6">0</col>
                <col code="7">31424</col>
            </row>
            <row code="2" s1="">
                <col code="1">0</col>
                <col code="2">0</col>
                <col code="3">0</col>
                <col code="4">0</col>
                <col code="5">0</col>
                <col code="6">0</col>
                <col code="7">0</col>
            </row>
        </section>
    </sections>
</report>
```

Now i try use Apache poi.

```
try {
            val wb = XSSFWorkbook("C:\\Users\\Vadim\\IdeaProjects\\forep2\\data\\templates\\xmlTest.XLSX")

            for (map in wb.customXMLMappings) {
                val exporter = XSSFExportToXml(map)

                val os = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                exporter.exportToXML(os, true)
                val xml = os.toString("UTF-8")
                println(xml)
            }
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            println(ex.message)
        }
```

But instead of what I want, I get only one element of the nested collection.

```
<report code="606010005012" form="5" format-version="1.3" period="2" shifr="un_p4" version="21-01-2021" year="2022">
    <title>
        <item name="" value=""/>
    </title>
    <sections>
        <section code="2">
            <row code="2" s1="">
                <col code="7">0</col>
            </row>
        </section>
    </sections>
</report>
```

I try to use method exportToXML. But instead of a nested collection, I get one root element of each node.

Comment: I don't think you can apply this kind of mapping to what appears to be a spreadsheet of different types of data mashed together. Your snippet of XML output kind of proves this -- most rows don't have titles, and the few that do don't have sections. My guess is that you have to parse the spreadsheet and create the respective XML manually. You could filter for rows that have `name` values and extract the data. Then then filter for rows with `code2` values, and extract that data. From that, you would construct your XML in the format you have shown above.

Comment: On approach would be to create JavaBeans that represent the structure you need to represent your required XML. You can create an instance of your JavaBean and fill in the data that you need. POI is a good way to get the data but it up to you to write the code to take the Sheet/Row/Cell data and fill in the fields on your JavaBeans. You can use something like jackson-dataformat-xml to deserialize your top level JavaBean instance as XML.

Comment: Another approach is to use XSSFExportToXml and use something like XSLT to transform the XML generated by XSSFExportToXml into the XML of the form you need.

Comment: Or you could copy https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/poi-ooxml/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/extractor/XSSFExportToXml.java and customise the code to change the names of the XML elements it produces.